# In order to set chrome as default browser for jupyter , i'm getting error while running config file- jupyter_notebook_config.py

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to set chrome as default browser for launching jupyter notebook. For this i'm following the usual steps-

1. In anaconda prompt, i fired- `jupyter notebook --generate-config`
   ,a config file 'jupyter_notebook_config.py' is created.
2. Opened the file in notepad & change the line `# c.NotebookApp.browser = ''` to `c.NotebookApp.browser = u'C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe %s'`
3. Saved the file & run the file, got an error, PF the Screenshot-
   [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ey2MB.png)

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "jupyter_notebook_config.py", line 99, in 
c.NotebookApp.browser = u'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe %s'
NameError: name 'c' is not defined

Can anyone please let me know what is object c here, which class it invokes?

Comment: I have the same problem. Ankan were you able to find the solution?

Comment: amango, we would find the answers someday. We need to keep trying finding people who knows this in this great stackoverflow community.

Answer (score 2):

In windows 10 - Goto file explorer - browse to C:\Users\your user name\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\runtime.  Locate the nbserver-####-open.html files.  Right click anyone of them. Select Properties (at bottom).  With popup window, choose OPEN WITH: change button (at top) and select browser of your choice.

Comment: I executed your mentioned steps, i was hoping it would definitely help. However, even after these steps , when i run `jupyter notebook` in anaconda console.it is not launching chrome browser automatically.  Could you please suggest am i missing something

Comment: Ankan, please confirm that you have chrome as your windows 10 default browser.  To verify goto: [Windows key] + S, type: default apps + [enter], Scroll down to "Web Browser" and see what is listed?. You can set default browser by clicking once on  whatever is listed. A list will popup to choose a different browser.  After selecting. you must restart Anaconda console for the changes to take.  I have changed my browser to IE, Edge, Firefox, and then back to chrome.  Restarting Anaconda each time.  Within Anaconda, If you use command prompt [jupyter notebook] the default browser worked each time.

Comment: Thanks Boomer, this is the most common thing that needs to be done at the very first step & i was missing this. Now when i ran command `jupyter notebook` , the conda started the kernel as well as launch the browser with local host page most importantly. Your help is appreciated!!

Comment: Glad to help Ankan!  Happy coding & stay safe!

Answer (score 1):

Why are you running `python jupyter_notebook_config.py`?

You are supposed to run `jupyter notebook` in the console. and *jupyter* should ideally read off the `config`, and you should get something like :

```
The Jupyter Notebook is running at:
[I 03:33:00.085 NotebookApp] http://localhost:8888/?token=...
```

Comment: I'm running `jupyter notebook` in anaconda console. Actually my concern was why it is not launching chrome browser automatically, every time i have to explicitly open google chrome & run the local host.